# emacs beginning-of-buffer slow

Tags: performance, emacs

I began experiencing a couple of days ago a very slow `beginning-of-buffer` command in emacs, especially with long files (60k+ lines). Oddly, using `goto-line 1` or even `end-of-buffer` operate normally.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the source for `beginning-of-buffer`, it's not much more than `(goto-char (point-min))`, which should be very fast.  Emacs has a profiler for lisp, so try that.

Comment: Thanks @jpkotta. I will run a profile and report.